# Can two deterministic turing-machines avoid each other in a sidewalk?

Tags: computability, turing-machines

Imagine a turn-based game where two robots are placed on opposite sides of a 16x16 board, facing each-other. Each robot, at each turn, can perform one of 2 moves: **move** (moves forward), **turn** (turns 90 degree; clockwise for the first robot, anti-clockwise for the second). They can also send messages to each-other, and behave according to arbitrary deterministic computations.

```
|_|_|_|_|v|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|^|_|_|_|_|
```

For simplicity, assume the behavior of the robots is determined by a Python function such as:

```
# just an example, not used
state = {}

# always go forwards
def brain(otherPos, myPos, message):
    return ("move", "hello")
```

This behavior is, of course, stupid, as it always goes forward and broadcasts the same message, ignoring the position of the other robot and the message sent by it. On this case, the robots would just go forward, until they colide and stop moving forever. But any logic could be implemented and the robots could collaborate in arbitrary ways. An improvement would be:

```
# just an example, not used
state = {turn: 0}

# always go forwards
def brain(otherPos, myPos, message):
    if state.turn === 0:
        return ("turn", "I'm turning")
    elif state.turn === 1:
        return ("move", "I'm moving horizontally")
    elif state.turn <= 4:
        return ("turn", "I'm turning again")
    else:
        return ("move", "Now I'm going forward, forever!")
```

This one would cause both robots to turn 90 degrees, move, then turn 3 times, and then move forward forever. They'd still collide and get stuck on the same column, though, because, as one turns clockwise, the other one turns anti-clockwise.

My question is: **is it possible to program a `brain` function in such a way that, after N turns, each robot ends up on the other side?**

Comment: Both turn to there left. Both move forward one time, then both turn to get there initial direction. Then both move forward. No ?

Comment: @dylan61 the trick is how to turn each robot on their left. The game seems to be formulated so that the robots always move symmetrically.

Comment: How _exactly_ does the game work? Do the robots take turns to move? If so, you can break the symmetry by using the fact that one of the robots moved to be adjacent to the other. How does message broadcasting work? Do the robots know their position?

Comment: For now, I'm voting to close as unclear since the rules aren't specified.

Comment: @DavidRicherby the game works in turns, each turn a robot picks a move, robot A moves, then robot B moves, and messages broadcasted are only received on the next turn (the robots can't know which one moved first).

Comment: @MaiaVictor Please edit the question to make these clarifications. Do the robots know their own position?

Comment: @DavidRicherby the answer is kinda obvious from the spirit of the question, though: they know their positions, but relative to their initial positions (so they start seeing the same position).

Comment: @MaiaVictor No, it's not at all obvious from the question. That's why I'm repeatedly asking you to clarify.

Comment: @DavidRicherby yes, it is obvious. I'm clearly setting up a scheme where robots are symmetric. The only reasonable interpretation is that they'd see the same position, and you know that. You're being overly pedantic for the sake of it. The only thing that would satisfy you is an interpreter. But pasting an interpreter here would make the question bloated and shy away readers. It is hard to find the equilibrium between satisfying the pedantic and making the question bearable.

Comment: @MaiaVictor No, I'm not being pedantic for the sake of it. You're expecting me to read your mind and, guess what?, I can't do that. I really don't understand your reluctance to just explicitly state what the rules of the game are, especially given that your question has been on the site for more than a week and still hasn't got a good answer.

Comment: @DavidRicherby you honestly didn't realize this is a symmetric game from all the previous answers? Whatever, though, I'm voting to close this question.

Answer (score 2):

You have to teach the robots how to keep track of their identity, either by remembering the initial position, or by signing their messages.
Then they can perform their individual programs. 
Something like this:

```
t = "turn"
m = "move"
program1 = [t, m, t, t, t, m, m, m, m, m, m, m]
program2 = [t, t, t, m, t, m, m, m, m, m, m, m]

def brain(otherPos, myPos, message):
    if message == "1":
        return (program1.pop(0), "2")
    else:
        return (program2.pop(0), "1")
```

Comment: Indeed, you could just do `if id==1 {/* run program 1 /*} else { /* run program 2 */}`. None of these ideas is forbidden by the question.

Comment: @DavidRicherby jmster's program would cause both robots to execute the second branch on the first turn, and receive message "1" on the second turn. Sorry for the delay in answering those questions, next time I ask something like that I'll provide an interpreter for absolute clarity.

Comment: @MaiaVictor I see, it 's a very special "turn-based game" you have.  In that case please specify what do myPos and otherPos mean. If at least one of them contain the absolute coordinates, the robots can use that to identify themselves on the first move. If each robot believes it stands on row 1, then sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to make them choose a random direction (left or right) and broadcast it, if they broadcast one direction and receive the other then they repeat and they do this until they both go once in the same direction. When they know this they move up the board.

Comment: Deterministic Turing machines have no access to randomness.

Comment: Ok, sorry, guess I didn't fully understand the question